# How to handle UDP socket clients in python

Tags: python, sockets, server, udp, python-3.7

in TCP sockets you bind then accept connections by s.accept() but in UDP socket you just bind server and anyone connect (if i am wrong correct me) so how to control the clients like for example if 5 clients connect to the server close the server or if someone connect to the server send him a message saying welcome to the server 
Thanks for any answers .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, UDP has no concept of 'sessions', so it won't know how many it is currently handling.

You will need to implement some kind of session management within your code to decide when a client is or is not active, and take action on that.

An example code section which should allow up to five clients and expire them after thirty seconds is below.

```
bind_ip = '192.168.0.1' ## The IP address to bind to, 0.0.0.0 for all
bind_port = 55555 ## The port to bind to
timeout = 30 ## How long before forgetting a client (seconds)
maximum = 5 ## Maximum number of clients

###
import socket
import time

## Create the socket as an internet (INET) and UDP (DGRAM) socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

## Bind to the server address and port
sock.bind((bind_ip, bind_port))

## Make a dict to store when each client contacted us last
clients = dict()

## Now loop forever
while True:
    ## Get the data and the address
    data, address = sock.recvfrom(1024)

    ## Check timeout of all of the clients
    for addr in clients.keys():
        ## See if the timeout has passed
        if clients[addr] < (time.time() - timeout):
            ## Expire the client
            print('Nothing from ' + addr + ' for a while. Kicking them off.')           
            clients.pop(addr)

    ## Check if there are too many clients and if we know this client
    if len(clients.keys()) > maximum and address not in clients.keys():
        print('There are too many clients connected!')
        continue    

    ## Update the last contact time
    clients[address] = time.time()

    ## Do something with the data
    print('Received from ' + str(address) + ': ' + str(data))
```

This is by no means the most efficient way to do this, and serves as an example only.

Related reading: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Communication_Networks/TCP_and_UDP_Protocols/UDP

Comment: Thanks so much , but can the server know that there is a client connected to the server without the client sending  message becuase as i see he only know the address of a client when server recieve a message or data from the client not when the client connect

Comment: Because of the way UDP works, the client is not connected to the server unless it is sending it data. UDP is often referred to as a 'connectionless' protocol.

As an analogy, imagine TCP as using a hose with a person at each end, and UDP as using buckets with one person moving the buckets (client) and one waiting for buckets (server).

The TCP server will know that there is water (data) that could be received while the hose is connected. The UDP server waiting for buckets doesn't know how many buckets there will be, and if the other person has wandered off for lunch, or has no more buckets

Comment: Added link to wikibooks article that can hopefully clarify things a bit better than I can. You can only fit so much in a SO comment.

Comment: Thanks , and why do i get a message too long error when i  try to send data (image) using udp sockets

Comment: I'm not certain, as I've honestly only used UDP for small transfers (multicast discovery, state updates, etc). I suspect it would be as the error suggests - the message is too long.

Could you try splitting your image up in to smaller parts and recombining it at the remote end? I suspect Python may be limiting you to the maximum size of a single UDP packet. Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#UDP_datagram_structure for further info.

Comment: you can't send more than 64k in one IP datagram.  if you want to transmit more then you need to use multiple datagrams.  this means you need to fragment your images when sending and reassemble them in the receiving code.  it's up to you to handle missing and out-of-order packets, also you should probably also use something closer 1500 byte datagrams (unless you know your network supports "jumbo frames")